# Android - ClassCastException when using R.id.resource

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

The errors says that im trying to cast a TextView into a Button, but I dont see anything wrong with my code

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_grass"
tools:context=".Game3Activity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/junk"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_woodslab" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/game3_q1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/junk"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_picturehole" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game3_q2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_wordhole"    
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/game3_choice2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/junk"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game3_choice1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/junk"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/game3_choice3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/game3_choice2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/junk"/>
```

Java onCreate function:

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.game3_q1);
textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.game3_q2);
```

Variables were already initialized as private variables (private ImageView image)etc 
The app immediately crashes after I try to set the imageview. Any solutions?

Comment: Where are image and textview declared?  They match the appropriate casts that you are doing?

Comment: as private variables
public class classname extends Activity{
private ImageView image;
private TextView textview;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. Eclipse and ADT are buggy like that, especially if you swap the places of two types of views in your .xml file.

Comment: Surprisingly this worked. This halted alot of my progress in other classes =.= It happened after i moved the views around the xml file.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty annoying. I'm waiting for Android Studio to gain a bit more ground and switching to it, constantly cleaning and rebuilding is a pain.

Comment: It's not a bug, really. When you generate `R.java`, it's based on the order of items encountered. If you change something's order, it won't be right again until you regenerate it. It's not Eclipse's fault, and it won't change in Android Studio unless they completely change the way R.java is created, which I don't see happening.

Comment: Interesting point. I don't see why the build process can't be tweaked to automatically regenerate R.java, though.

Comment: True, but that would mean reparsing/creating/compressing everything in `/res`, which is about half of what a clean build is.

Answer (score 0):

Either clean your project and rebuild, or take a look at which layout is called in your `Activity` `onCreate` method.

For instance, if `setContentView` does not reference the layout file you posted, then of course something bad is going to happen.

Note that I'm assuming the code you posted takes place in an `Activity`, possibly in `onCreate`, for lack of evidence to the contrary.

Post your whole stack trace and more code if this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported the correct classes:

```
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
```